# How to hide public classes in library Jar using ProGuard (or any other way)?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I want to build a library, but I don't want some classes to be exposed to the developer, but I do want them to be exposed to my library code and tests easily.

Is there a way to hide specific public classes using ProGuard or in any other way (like the @hide notation used in Android SDK)?

Comment: `exposed to my code` do you mean your code in your library, or somewhere else ?

Comment: Exposed to the code in my library

Comment: Then why are they `public`? Is your library so complicated that you need multiple packages? Or are they `public` because it is required by superclasses/interfaces?

Comment: some are required by superclasses, and I also need a way to instantiate them in my tests.

Comment: C'mon buddy, you are working with an opensource os, I believe if you set your desired license in your package and classes, no one will use them of course. and if don't trust me, why don't you use inner classes? or some very complex patterns? or wrong class names? name the login class with toy :), and I'm wondering you are talking about `Public` so `Public` is public no any exception

Comment: I want my library "end-users", to have the cleanest API possible. Android SDK did the same, but they used @hide annotation.

Comment: The `@hide` annotation works because the compile-time JAR (`android.jar` in your build path) is not the same as the run-time JAR. You only have one JAR, and so an `@hide`-style trick is not possible. "I also need a way to instantiate them in my tests" -- put your instrumentation tests in the same package as the classes themselves, at which point they can work with package-private classes and methods.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare for the @hide explanation. I'll do as you suggested and hide whats possible using the package modifier.

Answer (score 0):

the whole point of obfuscatin is that it hides the method for people on the outside, but references inside the library are updated. Typically, you'll have a

```
void myMethodWithAVeryExplicitName() {
    // Do Stuff
}

void otherMethod() {
    // Call the first method
    myMethodWithAVeryExplicitName();
}
```

It will be obfuscated as :

```
void a() {
    // Do Stuff
}

void b() {
    // Call the first method
    a();
}
```

Then Proguard has a lot of options for obfuscating or keeping public classes, classes that extend specific classes, members ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a facade (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) would help. The purpose of this pattern is similar with your problem. It offers a reduced to the outside world while it keeps all the bells and whistles inside the library.